# Can I import a stream table into a partitioned table in dolphindb database?

Tags: database-partitioning, dolphindb

Can I import a stream table into a partitioned table in dolphindb database?

I create a partitioned table as below:

```
login("admin", "123456")
dbPath="dfs://thermalDB"
stream = streamTable(10000:0,`id`ts`tem,[SYMBOL,TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE])
dbDate = database(, VALUE, 2021.03.17..2031.03.17)
dbID = database(,  HASH,  [SYMBOL,  50])
db=database(dbPath, COMPO,  [dbDate,  dbID])
db.createPartitionedTable(stream, "pt", `ts`id)
```

But it returns me an error:

```
A stream table does not support direct access. Please use sql query to retrieve data
```

How does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

The table passed into the function createPartitionedTable cannot be a stream table. You can write the code as follows:

```py
login("admin", "123456")
dbPath="dfs://thermalDB"
dbDate = database(, VALUE, 2021.03.17..2031.03.17)
dbID = database(,  HASH,  [SYMBOL,  50])
db=database(dbPath, COMPO,  [dbDate,  dbID])
t = table(1:0,`id`ts`tem,[SYMBOL,TIMESTAMP,DOUBLE])
db.createPartitionedTable(t, "pt", `ts`id)
```